# Why do i keep getting Errors in if else statements

Tags: c#

Part of a C Sharp code for a loan management system includes an if-else statements but i keep getting errors when giving the condition either with single or double quotes, brackets or not. What could be the problem

```
('+txtPassword.Text = " "()')



        if (
            {
            if
                 ('txtEmailAddress.Text == " " ');
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Fill out required fields!");
            }
            else if
                    (+txtPassword.Text == " "()')
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Fill Out Required Fields");
            }
            else if
                    ('+txtConfirmPassword.Text == " "()')
                    {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Fill Out Required Fields")
                    }
        }
            )
        { 

        else if (txtPassword.Text != txtConfirmPassword.Text)

                MessageBox.Show("Passwords don't match!");
```

Comment: Provide full code.

Comment: As @TanveerBadar mentions, without more information it's not possible to help you. Please take your time to read here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: if(txtPassword.Text == "Password"){}else{} for example

Answer (score 1):

Make you code something like this. I don't know much about that variables so I just fixed the error in if..else.

```
if(txtEmailAddress.Text == " ")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please Fill out required fields!");
}
else if(txtPassword.Text == " ")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Fill Out Required Fields");
    }
    else if(txtConfirmPassword.Text == " ")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Fill Out Required Fields")
        }
        else if (txtPassword.Text != txtConfirmPassword.Text)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Passwords don't match!");
            }
```